# Why does continuous linear functional $f$ in topological space $V$ have to have an inverse?

Tags: functional-analysis

Why does continuous linear functional $f$ in topological space $V$ have to have an inverse?

Like in the proof for kernel of continuous functional being closed.

https://mathproblems123.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/functional-is-continuous-iff-kernel-is-closed/

> If f is continuous then $\ker f=f^{-1}(0)$ ...

But how does one know $f^{-1}$ exists?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Preimage.html

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to have an inverse. The notation $f^{-1}(0)$ means the set of all vectors $v$ from the domain such that $f(v)=0$.

Comment: But isn't the argument that follows " If f is continuous then $\ker f=f^{-1}(0)$ and therefore is closed." based on $\{0\}$ being closed and then a continuous linear functional maps closed to closed by open mapping theorem? So to me it reads like it utilizes the inverse of $f$.

Comment: No, the argument doesn't use the open mapping theorem at all. The preimage of closed/open sets under a continuous function is always closed/open (respectively). That is actually the definition of continuity for functions between topological spaces. As $\{0\}$ is closed and $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed.